# IndexError: list index out of range (Chatbot is not working)

Tags: python, neural-network, chatbot

I Was Coding a chatbot, but it doesn't work Every time I Run my program and start A conversation.
I get that error code, why is that so and what can I do ?

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QMC3.png)

It says that there is something in line 46

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
tag = intents_list[0]["intent"] #line 46 
list_of_intents = intents["intents"]
for i in list_of_intents:
    if i ["tag"] == tag:
        result = random.choice(i["response"])
        break
return result
```

and it also says that there is a problem in line 59

```
while True:
message = input("")
ints = predict_class(message)
res = get_response(ints, intents) #line 59
print(res)
```

Comment: Your `predict_class` function returns an empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed looks kike `predict_class` returns an empty list so `intents_list[0]` does not exist and throws an out of bound on line 46. Line 59 is just the call stack, aka that is where you call the function that contains the error, which you do on that line.